# HOWTO run WSO2BAM as a launchd service?

Tags: macos, wso2, launchd, wso2-bam

Kindest - have installed WSO2BAM successfully, and have developed a service to gather data from an energy monitoring setup. What I would like to see now is how the wso2server.sh can be invoked automatically as part of a system reboot on MAC OSX Yosemite. I have developed a sample launchd XML (see below), and have tried multiple different options, but does not seem to hit the mark.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
                <key>CARBON_HOME</key>
                <string>/Users/jskogsta/local/wso2bam-2.4.1</string>
                <key>JAVA_HOME</key>
                <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.wso2.bam</string>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ServiceDescription</key>
        <string>WSO2BAM</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/jskogsta/local/wso2bam-2.4.1/logs/bam-launchd.stderr</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/jskogsta/local/wso2bam-2.4.1/logs/bam-launchd.stdout</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>root</string> </dict> </plist>
```

The intention is to get the WSO2BAM server to automatically execute upon reboot without the user logging in. Ideally would like then to run the WSO2BAM product as a named user rather than root.

Have anyone managed to get this done? Could not find any specific pointers to this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with MAC OSX, but I just want to inform you that you need to make sure wso2server.sh script is executed at the start-up. In your configuration, I don't see any command to run the WSO2 server.

If you know about configuring a Linux Service, you can apply **similar** concepts to MAC OSX.

Please refer following blog posts.

- http://blog.lasindu.com/2014/10/how-to-install-wso2-server-as-linux.html
- http://sumedhask.blogspot.com/2013/10/start-wso2-server-as-linux-service.html

Please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

I hope this helps.